# Devise current_user vs user_session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I'd like to limit a users scope, once authenticated, to a specific namespace. But they'll be dynamic (ie not a named route). example:

```
/rails/redteam/
/rails/blueteam/
/rails/greenteam/
```

or perhaps simply:

```
/rails/
...or...
/
```

if we know their 'team' then couldn't that somehow be assumed in the routing?

How best to set this up and handle this *securely?* should I store team name in user_session? Or, query the current_user for their group and verify it matches their known group(s) in a before_filter?

What about the routes themselves? basically glorified IDs, perhaps a permalink of sorts? dunno the "Rails way?"

btw- I'm aware of authorization gems like `CanCan` and `decl_auth` but trying to avoid their complexity, if possible, as I'm sorta a newb, if that wasn't obvious enough already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm aware of authorization gems like CanCan and decl_auth but trying to avoid their complexity, if possible

You're much better off taking the time to learn about one (or the other, or both) of these gems than to try rolling your own solution, IMO. Ultimately you'll run into complications as your requirements change, and without a good framework underlying your approach, problems are just bound to happen.

Comment: Kinda what I was afraid of... I'm really just looking for an *easy* way to prevent users from modifying (or viewing for that matter) any of another teams data.  What I see, or at least understand about authorization gems is that they *seem* to be more geared to specific *roles* (admin, user, moderator, etc.) and not so much about access or *ownership*. Am I making an incorrect assumption? If so perhaps you could recommend one of the gems...

Comment: With cancan it's all about Ability. "Am I Able to :update this object". How you implement that ability is up to you

Comment: I've only used `declarative_authorization`. CanCan is popular these days  and is reputedly easy to use -- I'd start with that.

Comment: Just re-watched Railscasts on **CanCan** and **decl_auth** and *both* sorta appear to be designed for something other than what I need...I must be missing something? These gems will take a few 'roles' and grant users broad permissions based on these 'roles'. I don't have any 'roles' per se...only team members. Team `has_many` Users. And there are an **undefined number of teams** (many more than we could hard code abilities for). If user is related to a team then they should have access to modify team resources. Does this really require CanCan or decl_auth? or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Neither CanCan or decl_auth _require_ you to use roles except in a rudimentary way -- you're free to modify the access methods to fit your needs. Your CanCan `ability` method for example might say something like  `can :read, TeamResource, :team_id => user.team.id` or some such, to restrict access to the current user's team. The key point is that the authors of those two gems have put a lot of time into thinking about the issues behind authorization -- you should leverage that. OTOH if you'd rather dive in and roll your own, by all means go for it :)

Comment: @zetetic - Thank you! You've been very helpful *(on this post and others)*!